# Calculate the mean of the normal distribution function $\frac1 {2\pi \sigma^2}exp[-\frac {(x-\mu)^2} {2\sigma^2}]$ by integration.

Tags: integration, statistics, expectation, means

I know that it must be $\mu$ but I cannot get the answer. This is my attempt so far:

Normal distribution function = $N(x)=\frac1 {2\pi \sigma^2}exp[-\frac {(x-\mu)^2} {2\sigma^2}]$

$$\langle x\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xN(x)dx$$ Where $N(x)$ is the normal distribution function.

Substitute $y=\frac{x-\mu} {\sqrt2 \sigma} $. The resulting integral is:

$$\frac 1{2\sigma^2 \sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}$$

Since the integral can be evaluated as $\sqrt\pi$ the mean that I calculate is $\frac 1{2\sigma^2}$ not $\mu$ but I don't know what I have done wrong. Please help.

Comment: You want to make the substitution $y = \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$ and use evenness (to adjust your limits of integration).

Comment: Wouldn't the integral still just evaluate to the same thing?

Comment: Nope. Try it out :)

Comment: The integrand is symmetric about $x = \mu$, so that must be the mean.

Comment: I see, that's a different substitution. I've been asked to use the substitution that I used above (it's in my maths problem sheet to do over the Christmas holidays). Could you help me using this substitution?

Comment: using your substitution would make it very hard when putting in $dy$

Comment: $N\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{2}}$.
Use substitution $u=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$.

Comment: @user3764899 It seems that you have forgotten a factor $\pi$ in your change of variable. See my answer please.

Comment: I also forgot the x from the integral $\langle x\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xN(x)dx$. Surely this makes a difference, should it be there?

Comment: Consult Sheldon Ross - Introduction to probability models example 2.7 for a good explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** The change of variable $\displaystyle y=\frac{x-\mu} {\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma}  $ rather gives you 
$$\langle x\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xN(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma \:y +\mu /\sqrt{\pi})e^{-y^2}dy=\mu$$ since the first integral vanishes, the second one being standard.

Comment: I forgot the x from the integral $\langle x\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xN(x)dx$. Surely this makes a difference, should it be there?

Comment: @user3764899 Yes, it should be there. Your point is just the factor $\pi$, either in the exponential, either as a factor of the gaussian density. You have to check it out slowly. Thanks.

Comment: With the x there It becomes completely different. I get the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty ye^{-y^2}$

Comment: Have I done something wrong?

Comment: @user3764899 No, it is $$ (x=)\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma \:y +\mu$$ instead of $y$ only in the integrand...

Comment: how did you get the $\mu /\sqrt \pi$? I got $\frac{\sqrt2 \sigma \mu}{2 \pi \sigma^2}$

Comment: I've got it. I wrote it down wrong; thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$N\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{2}}$.
Use substitution $u=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$.

Note that $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{2}}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{2}}d\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$.

Comment: If I substitute $y=\frac{x-\mu}{\sqrt 2 \sigma}$ then $dy=\frac {dx}{\sqrt2 \sigma}$ doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is what you will get by that substitution.